# Create a timer that will go off at specific times based on minutes from an array for multiple time blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

So I'm working on a code where I am creating nested timers where a user simply needs to input a time in minutes that they would like to do something for. The program divides the time into x number of minute blocks of time and sets off a random alarm within that block. I already have the code to figure out the number of time blocks and at what minute within those time blocks to set off the alarm. However, I am stuck on creating a function to generalize the creation of time blocks and alarm times. So that each alarm goes off after the designated number of minutes in each time block. I know how I could set up the first alarm but not a generalized alarm. How I would set up the first timer is below. In the example below the total is for 60min, and within a 15min block of time an alarm will go off at a specific minute mark within each 15min block of time.

```
# t is  the desired time in minutes
t = 60
#total work time in seconds
ts = t * 60

# the times in minutes each alarm will go off in a 15-minute block
alarms = [5 , 3 , 8 , 10]
alarm_1 = alarms[0] * 60

#alarm1 = ts - (alarms[0] * 60)
alarm_return = 30


while alarm1  > 0:

    # Timer represents time left on countdown
    alarm_1_timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = alarm_1)
    
    # prints time left
    print(alarm_1_timer, end="\r")

    # Delays the program one second
    time.sleep(1)

    # Reduces total time by one second
    alarm_1-= 1

print("alarm 1")

while alarm_return  > 0:

    # Timer represents the time left on countdown
    alarm1_return_timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = alarm_return)
    
    print(alarm1_return_timer, end="\r")

    # Delays the program one second
    time.sleep(1)

    # Reduces total time by one second
    alarm_return -= 1

print("alarm_return")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue).  Objects are sorted in the queue and extracted by smallest first.  Enter the times in any order and they will be extracted earliest first.  Then compute the time to wait until that time occurs.

Since your alarms are relative to an interval of time (every 15 minutes in a 60-minute window, for example), you just need to step through the intervals and add the offsets needed for the alarms in each inteval.  `compute_alarms` below does the computation.

```py
import datetime as dt
import queue
import time

def now():
    # Do time math in UTC.  Daylight Savings Time
    # can mess up other time zones on transition days.
    return dt.datetime.now(tz=dt.timezone.utc)

def add_alarm(q, minutes):
    q.put((now() + dt.timedelta(seconds=minutes * 60)))

def compute_alarms(total_time, interval_offsets):
    # total_time and interval offsets in minutes
    interval = total_time / len(interval_offsets)
    for i, a in enumerate(interval_offsets):
        yield interval * i + a

def wait_next_alarm(q):
    try:
        a = q.get_nowait()
    except queue.Empty:
        # no alarms in queue
        return False
    # How long to wait until alarm.
    remaining = (a - now()).total_seconds()
    # Check in case the alarm is passed.
    if remaining > 0:
        # wait for alarm time
        time.sleep(remaining)
    return True

q = queue.PriorityQueue()
total_time = 60
interval_offsets = 5, 3, 8, 10
for alarm in compute_alarms(total_time, interval_offsets):
    add_alarm(q, alarm)

start = now()
while wait_next_alarm(q):
    print(now() - start) # how long did we wait?
```

Output:

```
0:05:00.012623
0:18:00.011207
0:38:00.002175
0:55:00.002177
```

Comment: Thank you for the response it gives me some ideas, but that doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do.  If there is one main alarm time which is 60 minutes and I have 4 alarms, then within the 4 equally divided 15-minute blocks there should be one alarm. so the first alarm would go off after 5 minutes the next alarm would go off (15min - 5min) +3min = 13min after the first alarm or really within 3 minutes of the 2nd 15-minute block the next would be the same with it going off after 20min and so on. These times are randomized and there is only 1 user input total time in minutes.

Comment: @randomdev2357 So this code still works just need to calculate `[(15 * i) + offset for i, offset in enumerate((5,3,8,10))]` and set those alarm times, which would be `[5,18,38,55]`.

Comment: @randomdev2357 Added logic mentioned above.

Comment: That is what I was going to do believe it or not. which is create that offset